# Clickhouse GROUP BY milliseconds

Tags: datetime, rows, clickhouse, milliseconds

How do I GROUP BY 0.004 seconds using the timestamps? I want to calculate the averages of 4 consecutive rows and have a table with a quarter of the values in the new table.

```
INSERT INTO sensor_1 Values
('2021-01-01 00:00:00.000', 1.52), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.001', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.002', 1.42), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.003', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.004', 1.42), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.005', 1.52), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.006', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.007', 1.42), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.008', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.009', 1.42),
('2021-01-01 00:00:00.010', 1.55), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.011', 1.45), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.012', 1.55), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.013', 1.45), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.014', 1.35), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.015', 1.55), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.016', 1.45), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.017', 1.55), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.018', 1.45), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.019', 1.35),
('2021-01-01 00:00:00.020', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.021', 1.44), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.022', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.023', 1.44), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.024', 1.34), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.025', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.026', 1.44), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.027', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.028', 1.44), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.029', 1.34),
('2021-01-01 00:00:00.030', 1.53), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.031', 1.43), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.032', 1.53), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.033', 1.43), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.034', 1.33), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.035', 1.53), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.036', 1.43), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.037', 1.53), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.038', 1.43), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.039', 1.33);
```

How do I GROUP BY 0.004 seconds using the timestamps? I want to calculate the averages of 4 consecutive rows and have a table with a quarter of the values in the new table.

Answer (score 0):

At first sight, I would use unix timestamp format (with milliseconds support) and then use modulo to group by 4 items.

It will be easier to group all rows by second, 1/10s or 1/100s than 4/1000s

Comment: SELECT
    when,
    toUnixTimestamp64Milli(when) AS unix_timestamp,
    value
FROM sensor_1
                                                How do I use modulo? Can you please show me an example?