# CLICKHOUSE GROUP BY 4 milliseconds

Tags: sql, group-by, timestamp, unix-timestamp, clickhouse

I want to average 4 consecutive rows (every 4 milliseconds). I want to GROUP BY N milliseconds. How can I do that using the timestamp, or UNIX timestamp using modulo? Basically, I want to group by 4 rows, then average those 4 rows then move to the next 4 rows. Please share the script.
[Im stuck here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJA2r.png)

```
INSERT INTO sensor_1000 Values
('2021-01-01 00:00:00.000', 1.52), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.001', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.002', 1.42), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.003', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.004', 1.42), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.005', 1.52), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.006', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.007', 1.42), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.008', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.009', 1.42),
('2021-01-01 00:00:00.010', 1.55), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.011', 1.45), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.012', 1.55), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.013', 1.45), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.014', 1.35), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.015', 1.55), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.016', 1.45), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.017', 1.55), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.018', 1.45), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.019', 1.35),
('2021-01-01 00:00:00.020', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.021', 1.44), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.022', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.023', 1.44), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.024', 1.34), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.025', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.026', 1.44), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.027', 1.54), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.028', 1.44), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.029', 1.34),
('2021-01-01 00:00:00.030', 1.53), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.031', 1.43), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.032', 1.53), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.033', 1.43), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.034', 1.33), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.035', 1.53), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.036', 1.43), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.037', 1.53), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.038', 1.43), ('2021-01-01 00:00:00.039', 1.33),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clickhouse GROUP BY milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70461874/clickhouse-group-by-milliseconds)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    toUnixTimestamp64Milli(now64(3)) AS x,
    intDiv(x, 4) * 4 AS y,
    x - y AS diff
┌─────────────x─┬─────────────y─┬─diff─┐
│ 1640362330078 │ 1640362330076 │    2 │
└───────────────┴───────────────┴──────┘


select intDiv( toUnixTimestamp64Milli ( ts ), 4) * 4 rounded_ts, ....
from
group by rounded_ts
```